# How can a jenkins plugin get the value of a configuration setting?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm creating a Jenkins plugin which is a post-build action. I want the plugin to read the value of the "Root POM" field in the job configuration page. I've been looking through the Javadocs for [hudson.model.AbstractBuild](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/index.html?hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html) and trying getBuildVariables(), getEnvironment() etc. but I don't see anything relevant.

I guess as a last resort I could configure my plugin to prompt the user for the root pom, but the problem is that management wants a plugin that can be deployed automatically on every build without any action on the user's part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want a plugin to read the configuration of another plugin (the maven one)? If so, I believe you should use something like

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor(RequiredDesc.class);
```

Your required class might be hudson/maven/Maven3Builder depending on what you are trying to do.

[Discussion](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Plugin-dependencies-and-reading-config-values-from-other-plugins-td4176633.html)

**Update**

I was wrong. This seems to work for me:

```
    if (build instanceof hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild) {
        try {
            hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild b = (hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild) build;
            hudson.EnvVars envVars = b.getEnvironment(listener);
            String rootPOM = b.getProject().getRootPOM(envVars);
            listener.getLogger().println("rootPOM: " + rootPOM);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            listener.getLogger().println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't compile: `cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol  : method getDescriptor(java.lang.Class<hudson.maven.Maven3Builder>)` I guess I need to cast it somehow? Please bear with me, my java programming experience is limited let alone jenkins plugin development and I've sort of been thrown in at the deep end!